# How should I check if all numbers in a tensorflow Tensor are all binary

Tags: python, tensorflow

How should I judge if all numbers in a tensorflow Tensor are either 0 or 1?

```
bad_mask = tf.Variable([[0.0,1.0,0.2,0.0,0.0], [0.0,5.0,0.0,2.3,0.0]])
good_mask = tf.Variable([[0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0], [0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0]])
```

I want to use `tf.assert`.

Comment: im not familiar with `tensorflow` , but do you think `regex` could help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this code (tested):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

bad_mask = tf.Variable([[0.0,1.0,0.2,0.0,0.0], [0.0,5.0,0.0,2.3,0.0]])
good_mask = tf.Variable([[0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0], [0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0]])

x = tf.Assert( tf.reduce_all( 
    tf.logical_or( tf.equal( good_mask, 0.0 ), tf.equal( good_mask, 1.0 ) )
), [ good_mask ] )

y = tf.Assert( tf.reduce_all( 
    tf.logical_or( tf.equal( bad_mask, 0.0 ), tf.equal( bad_mask, 1.0 ) )
), [ bad_mask ] )

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run( tf.global_variables_initializer() )
    print( sess.run ( x ) )
    print( sess.run ( y ) )
```

Will output:

> None

and

> InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [[0 1 0.2]...]
>   [[Node: Assert_4/AssertGuard/Assert = Assert[T=[DT_FLOAT], summarize=3, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Assert_4/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch, Assert_4/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch_1)]]

as desired.

Comment: I got a error...
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 167, in Assert
    xs = ops.convert_n_to_tensor(data)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1202, in convert_n_to_tensor
    as_ref=False)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1157, in internal_convert_n_to_tensor
    raise TypeError("values must be a list.")
TypeError: values must be a list.

Comment: Yes, sorry, `tf.Assert()` requires the data to print in case the assert failed to be in a list. Changed, tested, inserted full code into answer, works now.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the tensor to a list using `tf.unstack` and then check that all the values are either 0 or 1.